# combine row with different name for a column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a sample data set:

```
import pandas as pd


df = {
  'columA':['1A','2A','3A','4A','5A','6A'],
 'count': [ 1, 12, 34, 52, '3',2],
 'columnB': ['a','dd','dd','ee','d','f']
}


df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

it looks like this:

```
 columA columnB count
   1A       a     1
   2A      dd    12
   3A      dd    34
   4A      ee    52
   5A       d     3
   6A       f     2
```

**Update: The combined 2A and 3A name should be something arbitrary like 'SAB' or '2A plus 3A', etc., I used '2A|3A' as the example and it confused some of the people.** 
I want to sum up the count the rows 2A and 3A and give it a name SAB
desired output:

```
  columA  columnB count
   1A        a     1
   SAB      dd    46
   4A        ee    52
   5A        d     3
   6A        f     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `groupby` on columnB

```
df = {'columA':['1A','2A','3A','4A','5A','6A'],
      'count': [ 1, 12, 34, 52, '3',2],
      'columnB': ['a','dd','dd','ee','d','f']}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df.groupby('columnB').agg({'count': 'sum', 'columA': 'sum'})


        columA  count
columnB     
a       1A      1
d       5A      3
dd      2A3A    46
ee      4A      52
f       6A      2
```

If you're concerned about the index name you can write a function like so.

```
def join_by_pipe(s):
    return '|'.join(s)

df.groupby('columnB').agg({'count': 'sum', 'columA': join_by_pipe})


        columA  count
columnB     
a       1A      1
d       5A      3
dd      2A|3A   46
ee      4A      52
f       6A      2
```

Comment: how can I rename 2A3A to 2|3A during the process? this is just a sample dataset but this part is important for my real dataset

Comment: @Jessica I have made an edit to add in your pipe. The solution depends on whether you're going to always have `A` or if there could be some other letter. Edit it into your question and I can give it a go!

Comment: As an e.g. this `def join_by_pipe(s): 
    return '|'.join(s.str.replace('A', '')) + 'A'` does what you wanted but it might not genrealise for your dataset if you have, lets say, `5B` as values.

Comment: I used 2A|3B as an example for a diff. name, in reality the new name would be 'general hospital' something like that, so it was by accident and i didn't mean it should be '|' , so how can I change columA name to any name I want?

Comment: @Jessica I think you either need reword your question to include this, or, as this answers your original question, accept this answer and open another question specific to the naming.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I gave you a vote up and reworded my question.